# Safari web push doesn't sent

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobile-services

I successfully configured and connected Safari Web Push. When sending request through the REST api I get a successful code 202 but the push notification does not received by Safari browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Safari web push notification you need to pass all the optional settings when you are sending the notification. For example:

{ "message": { "alert": "Safari Web Notification with icon and title for registered devices ", "url": "www.ibm.com" }, "settings" : { "safariWeb": { "title": "Flight A998 Now Boarding", "body": "Boarding has begun for Flight A998.", "action": "View", "urlArgs": ["www.google.com"] } }, "target":{ "platforms":["WEB_SAFARI"] } }